# Como atualizar um campo no MongoDB

Tags: javascript, array, mongodb, sql-update

Considerando a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad69abb3630404194c80571"),
"cnpj" : 2352345234523452,
"razao_social" : "Lalala Ltda.",
"fantasia" : " "aiufhdiua Ltda.",
"dt_criacao" : ISODate("2018-04-18T01:09:15.076Z"),
"usuarios" : [ ],
"sensores" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "leituras" : [ ]

    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "leituras" : [ ]
    }
]
```

}

Como eu faço para atualizar esse documento com o documento abaixo apenas no campo `sensores.id:2`?

```
{ "latitude": 45.435435, "longitude": 120.09345493 }
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente executar o seguinte comando na consola do mongo: (substitua a `<collection>` pelo nome correcto)

```
db.<collection>.update({"sensores.id" : 2 }, { $set: { "sensores.$.leituras.latitude" : "45.435435", "sensores.$.leituras.longitude": "120.09345493"}})
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!